# Появляется пробел в конце кода php

Tags: php, html

Ситуация следующая: при вставке кода для смены сцветовой гаммы на странице WordPress в конце появляется пустой символ. Вот как это выглядит:
[![Отладчик браузера][1]][1]

[![Добавлие кода php для определения темы, которую задал ползователь]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f01964a46ceb85bd3776b8aef008c975 - обработчик браузера.
https://gyazo.com/f01964a46ceb85bd3776b8aef008c975 - код theme-options

Comment: @Anton Komyshan возможно, проблема в коде, который на скрине.
https://gyazo.com/f01964a46ceb85bd3776b8aef008c975
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs1kV.png - вот скрин с отладчика браузера

Comment: может вы сперва примете get_option() в переменную, а уж опосля вставите её в ссылку?